# MVC 5 Web Application Share Master files

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, master-pages

I have a large ASP.NET 4.5.1 Web Application that I have just successfully added MVC 5 to (using this [guide](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2013/12/30/so-you-inherited-an-asp-net-web-forms-application.aspx) )

I am now presented with the challenge of making all MVC content look just like my Web Forms content. I use .Master files in all of my Web Forms as Microsoft intended, but I am not seeing a clear solution for how to share these .Master files with my MVC views (since Layouts appear to have replaced .Master files).

The almighty [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx) posted a few options for MVC 3 over four years ago, but I can't believe that Microsoft hasn't come up with a cleaner way to share .Master pages between Forms and Views.

My GoogleFoo has failed me and I'm hoping someone has a slicker new way of making my frankenstein web application look consistent across both Forms and Views.

Comment: What issue are you having specifically that makes layouts not work?  Can you not use sections?

Comment: Layouts would work, but my .master page is currently not comprised of user controls (ascx's) so the first option that Hanselman proposed would require me to first re-write my .master page to be a series of UserControls which could then be utilized by both the master and layout files. The ascx option (along with the extension method option) is valid, but I just figured that since 2011 and MVC3, there had to be some kind of progress made in helping master pages be consumed by mvc applications. But, it sounds like the architecture of the .NET view engines may just be the limitation?